# Nomenclature for LAN reverse DNS?

Tags: dns

Imagine two company website server hosts are on the same LAN:

- www.bluejeans.com   at LAN=192.168.1.2
- www.greenjeans.com  at LAN=192.168.1.3

and behind the same WAN IP address.  An inbound WAN HTTP request (port 80) would need to process receive the request decide whether to forward the request to LAN address 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.3.  Ideally the gateway device (router) would be able to map blue and green URL requests to the correct LAN IP.

## What is the name of this service?

Once I understand then nomenclature for the class of service, then I can evaluate  specific instances.  I would like to implement (test) this capability  on a UNIX based router (RT-AC68U Optware) or a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as a "[reverse proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/)". Both [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) have this functionality, as does Varnish.

Personally and professionally, I've used Apache2 as a reverse proxy. I've tried with Varnish and never got a successful implementation, but of course this doesn't mean it won't work for you.

Things to remember

- Your real content website often needs to know it's behind an accelerator
- Do run the reverse proxy with https (LetsEncrypt, for example, has plenty of automation to generate and renew SSL certificates)
- Don't run the real website with https, but ensure it thinks it's running https
- You will need to rewrite not only incoming and outgoing URLs but also outgoing content

Comment: as well as haproxy and squid

Comment: @A.B please feel free to add. I know nothing about haproxy, and I haven't used squid in a very long time.

Comment: Well I can also add this: haproxy  (and I think nginx too) can also do "tls passthrough" to forward https traffic without decoding it, because up to now the SNI client hello message carries the site hostname in clear. But I wouldn't give an answer for this, I think OP should already understand that whatever is used, it's not just routing.

Comment: No URL or content needs to be rewritten in neither way. The HTTP requests that go to these two different public website addresses will carry a different HTTP Hostname header. And even these request go to the same IP address, same port, the reverse proxy that handles these requests can differentiate on the Hostname alone and decide weather a request goes to IP .1.2. or to 1.3. Any response that comes back only carries URLs that refer back to the site and these URLs are handled as the original URL.

Comment: Any website that needs to know it's behind an accelerator (aka: cache) is poorly written to a certain extent. A real content website has all cache headers well prepared, sent along the content, and these cache headers are handled properly by all upstream cache servers.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue a HTTP request in a browser to a domain name by entering an URL, the browser first looks up the IP address of that domain, then opens a connection to that IP on port #80 and sends this (there are tons of variations but for an example it suffices):

Test URL: [http://www.bluejeans.com/testurl](https://google.com)

```
> GET /testurl HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.20.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.20.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2t zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: www.bluejeans.com
> Accept: */*
```

As you see, the original URL is split, the domain name you targeted is now carried in the `Host:` header and the remaining URL path is the parameter of `GET`.
This is the information that reaches the webserver, reverse proxy, cache or any middleware that is listening on the specific IP:port.

This information alone is enough to make a decision on the incoming request which website it wants to reach and it can be properly *proxy-ed* to that server that really serves the request (sometimes called `origin server`).